# How do I make only a single call to the move-constructor?

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics, unique-ptr

How do I make the code below only call the move-constructor **once**?

**OUTPUT**

```
MC
MC
```

**CODE**

```
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

struct Bar
{
        Bar() { }
        Bar( Bar&& rhs )
        {
                std::cerr << "MC\n";

                for( auto& p : rhs.m_v )
                {
                        std::cerr << "inside loop\n";
                        m_v.push_back( move( p ));
                }
        }
        std::vector< std::unique_ptr< Bar >>  m_v;
};

int main()
{
        Bar b;

        std::map<int,Bar> m;
        m.insert( std::make_pair( 1, std::move( b )));
}
```

**EDIT**

It looks like `emplace` is the right answer - but unfortunately, it's not in gcc 4.7.2 yet...  ...is there some way I can alias this to `insert` and then remove it when it's properly implemented?

Comment: `map::emplace` seems to work with [gcc 4.8.0](http://liveworkspace.org/code/1FWK1L$26), if you don't mind installing a non-release version.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`std::map::emplace`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/emplace):

```
m.emplace(1, std::move(b));
```

Answer (score 4):

Essentially by using `emplace` instead of `insert`:

```
m.emplace(1, std::move(b));
```

Comment: ack - I'm using gcc 4.7.2 - is there a work-around or something I can do in anticipation of its implementation?

Comment: hmm... I think I'm getting a `sandbox.cpp:27:4: error: ‘class std::map<int, Bar>’ has no member named ‘emplace’` - maybe something is wrong with my install

Comment: @kfmfe04 Odd, I get that too; I could have sworn I already used that.

Comment: No, there is no simple workaround, which is one of the reasons this functionality is required by the standard.

Comment: FWIW, this works fine with clang (latest Apple Xcode version).

Comment: @Brett But only when specifying `-stdlib=libc++` (otherwise complete mayhem ensues weirdly enough …).

Comment: @KonradRudolph - C++11 only works properly with `-std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++`. Otherwise it uses the (old) `libstdc++`.